# two complement encoding negative value

Tags: c, encoding, numbers, twos-complement

while reading the book Computer System a programmer perspective.I have found that if i take most negative value in the range of a data type for example :

```
char a = -128;
a = - a;
```

The variable a will still have the value -128 and i understand that but when i do

```
char a = 50;
char b = -128;
char r = a - b;
```

It give me the correct result -78, why is that?? it because the automatic promotion to int or there is a hardware subtraction without needing to calculate  two complement of -128??

Comment: sorry a must have the value 50 and b the value -128

Comment: I get `-78` too when I `printf` `r`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char a = -128;` means `char a = 0x80;`, so at the promotion to int it will be `0xFFFFFF80`.
`-0xFFFFFF80` = `0x00000080` and that is casted to an char `0x80` which is the same as the start value.

```
char a = -128;
char b = 50;
char r = a - b;
```

0xFFFFFF80
0xFFFFFFCE
   =
0xFFFFFF4E

so `4E` will be written in `r`, which is +78.

live demo: https://ideone.com/sjyBOa